# Rails Fetch Data From Remote Oracle DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I have a customer that want us to connect their remote Oracle DB and fetch only Customer table data. I do not need to do create/update or any other functionality just get from one remote db table data. How can I do that with Ruby on Rails?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Use Active Records for ORM

Comment: I don't need to user ORM for this. I need to fetch some data from remote oracle db and save as csv. How can I handle with this?

Comment: you can use (OCI8) library. refer https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/fernandez-rails-connections.html#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20connect%20to,similar%20to%20JDBC%20or%20ODBC.